# Url mismatch, django template link

Tags: django, templates, hyperlink, path, href

I've got a prob with a link in the sidebar of my django site, in the template it's like that:

```
<li><a href="profile">Profile</a></li>
```

while in the urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/profile/$', 'auth.views.show_profile', name='profile')
```

When i access it from the main page with url: e.g  `/1001/profile/` it loads fine but when I try to access it from another subpage with url: e.g `/1001/forms/profile/` i get the error: The current URL, `/1001/forms/profile/`, didn't match any of these. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because "profile" is a relative URL, and a relative URL is appended to the current URL - the resulting address is not valid across the whole site. Seems like you should use an absolute URL in your case.

At the template you can try something like:

```
<a href="/{{ request.user.id }}/profile/">Profile</a>
```

**UPDATE**

To get request available in templates you have to add django.core.context_processors.request to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. I'm not sure if it is added by default.

Comment: I tried 'em but now I get 'Oops! Google Chrome could not find profile'!

Comment: Is the user authenticated and are you using a RequestContext?

Comment: I just did it, there was a conflict and the user id was not passed correctly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to add your second subpage url in urls like you did for `/1001/profile/`

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/form/profile/$', 'auth.views.show_profile', name='profile_form')
```

and also correct your code as @Paulo mentioned or you can also do it through reverse url.

```
<a href="{% url profile request.use.id %}">Profile</a>
```